# Path.relativize behaviour when "dot directory" is included

Tags: java, nio2

About `Path.relativize` method you can read

> [...] This method attempts to construct a relative path that when
>   resolved against this path, yields a path that locates the same file
>   as the given path. For example, on UNIX, if this path is "/a/b" and
>   the given path is "/a/b/c/d" then the resulting relative path would be
>   "c/d". [...]

So this

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/a/b");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/a/b/c/d");
System.out.println(p1.relativize(p2));
```

outputs

```
c\d
```

As long as I understand the whole idea is like asking *"I'm currently in the location given by path `p1`, how do I get to path `p2` from here?"*.

But to me, given that `/a/b` and `/a/b/.` represent the same location, I'd expect the answer to the above question to be the same, while

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/a/b/.");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/a/b/c/d");
System.out.println(p1.relativize(p2));
```

prints

```
..\c\d
```

instead. In this case, if I'm in the location given by `p1`, applying `..\c\d` I won't get to `p2` but to `\a\c\d`, so... Either there's some inconsistency or my metaphore is wrong. So, could you help me to understand where and why is my metaphore wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path segment `.`, for the purposes of `p1`, is considered just another name, not a special case for *the current directory*.

If you want it to mean the current directory, [`normalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize--) the path.

> The precise definition of this method is implementation dependent but
>   in general it derives from this path, a path that does not contain
>   redundant name elements. In many file systems, the `"."` and `".."` are
>   special names used to indicate the current directory and parent
>   directory. **In such file systems all occurrences of `"."` are considered
>   redundant.** If a `".."` is preceded by a non-`".."` name then both names
>   are considered redundant (the process to identify such names is
>   repeated until it is no longer applicable).

Comment: I know how normalize works, but are you saying that to `resolve` and `relativize` both `.` and `..` are just labels like `foo` or `bar` could be?

Comment: @LuigiCortese I'm starting to have some doubts, but for the inputs of `relativize`, yes. For `resolve`, I can't decide based on the javadoc.

Comment: @LuigiCortese Ignore what I just said. Neither of them interpret `.` or `..` in any special way. I was confused by an example I tried. (Thanks for the comment, but I'm always depressed. This is the only hat that expresses that.)

Comment: I deleted the comment because I was not sure about `resolve`, I'm editing the question, stay tuned!

Comment: No need to edit the question, what I find confusing is that (from javadoc) *if this path is "`/a/b`" and the given path is "`/a/x`" then the resulting relative path may be "`../x`"* so they're giving a meaning to that `..`. I'll investigate further...

Comment: @LuigiCortese Towards the end of the javadoc of `relativize`, it talks about the relation between `relativize` and `resolve` in terms of _normalized_ paths. So the `Path` that will be returned will potentially contain `.` and `..`, but they won't be interpreted as special. When you normalize them, they will.